# What is the value of a <textarea> if there is no text in it?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to show an `alert` when a certain function is run and an if statement in that function finds that the `<textarea>` has no text in it. I tried:

```
<textarea rows="10" style="display: block;"id="textLoc" placeholder="Text to test"cols="50"></textarea>  

text = document.getElementById('textLoc').value;

    if (text == "") {
    //show alert
    }
```

but it did not work. Any ideas?

Update: I tried printing the value of the `<textarea>` in an alert and it showed the value as undefined. I then tried `typeof text == "undefined"` and it did not work either.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the first line? What exactly is "<textarea> value"?

Comment: Ok, there you go. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<textarea>` element actually exists, `value` will be `""` (empty string) if there is no text in it. From your comment on the other answer, "cannot read property of null" means `document.getElementById('textLoc')` is returning `null`: make sure that the ID of the element is correct.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the `<textarea>` html in the question.

Comment: @chromedude: It works for me on Firefox/Chrome/IE. Sounds like your problem is elsewhere. Did you actually post all the relevant code?

Comment: I am trying to, but when using jsfiddle or jsbin it does not seem to think I have added js. Plus most the code is not applicable. Its about 200 lines long.

Comment: @chromedude: You don't need to post everything, but to debug, I would start by commenting out everything except what is required and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @casablanca I can't get it because for some reason the way jsfiddle and jsbin run the code my code weirdly interferes. not sure why

Comment: exactly what code are you using? I tried the code by itself and it did not work.

Comment: @chromedude: See this: http://jsbin.com/asusa4/ - `value` is empty and `value == ''` is true.

Comment: @casablanca but that does not prove the if statement

Comment: @chromedude: `alert(value == '')` shows `true`, which is the same as the if statement executing. You could change it to `if (value == '') alert(...);` and that would mean the same.

Comment: ahh... I see. I didn't know that shortcut. That doesn't work in my case because I have an if statement and that is the second clause could you check that out?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is quite flexible. Try:

```
if (text) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. It is giving a console error of "Cannot read property 'value' of null". I don't know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space before the `id` attribute in your HTML, which is why `id` is not being set, and hence you can't get an element by that ID.

If you're getting "Cannot read property 'value' of null", then that means there's no element with that ID (i.e., getElementById returned null). If a textarea actually exists, the value is `''` when empty. To safeguard against errors where you access a property of null:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textLoc');
if (textarea && textarea.value) ...
```

Comment: but... textLoc is not defined in that code. So what is it trying to do?

Comment: just tried that and didn't change anything. The id part, I am using the value of the `<textarea>` in other parts of the code without a problem so I do not think its a problem with refrencing it or with the `<textarea>`

Comment: hmm... ok, its about 200 lines of code that mostly does not apply.

Comment: ok, exactly what code are you using? I tried it seperate from my code and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
<textarea rows="10" style="display: block;"id="textLoc" 
placeholder="Text to test"cols="50">
```

is not correct.

The tag should be closed:

```
<textarea rows="10" style="display: block;"id="textLoc" 
placeholder="Text to test"cols="50"/>
```

Comment: You should mention this as a comment to the original question, as this doesn't actually answer it. Two more things: i) there should be spaces between attributes, and ii) `<textarea>` needs a closing tag to function properly.